# High order splitting methods for ODE with different timesteps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to solve numerically an ODE of the type
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = A f + B f
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are two different operators. $A$ is very cheap to evaluate but stiff and it requires very small time steps. $B$, on the other hand, is very expensive (orders of magnitude more expensive than evaluating $A$) but stable and allows for very long time steps (two orders of magnitude larger than the ones I need for a stable integration of $A$).

If I try to use Runge-Kutta methods to propagate the equation, then I am forced to use very small time steps due to $A$'s stiffness, which in turns forces me to evaluate $B$ uselessly many times, with unbearable costs.

I am looking for a high order splitting method which allows me to use very different time steps for the propagation of the two operators. It would also be great if I could propagate the two operators with different methods (for instance an explicit RK for $B$ and an implicit one for $A$).